# C++ Visual Studio 2010 Exclude file from project/build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, header

I have a C++ project originally developed under Linux (Eclipse). Since I wanted my app to run under Windows as well I extracted the non-portable portion of the code into a separate NonPortable.hpp(cpp) file. My plan was to share the code in a Visual Studio project while excluding the Linux non-portable stuff and including the Windows versions.

```
/I"D:\...\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PROJECT\include" /I"D:\SHARED FOLDER\include"
```

The first path contains the Windows version of NonPortable.hpp while the second path contains all other header file (including the Linux version of NonPortable.hpp). Now the problem is that no matter what I do the compiler always includes (also) the Linux version.
I have tried excluding it from the project/build with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some of the other headers include NonPortable.hpp, they will first look for it in their own directory.

I would have put the system dependent code in two separate directories, one for Windows and one for Linux. Then you can use slightly different include paths on each system, just as you started to do here.